# Hyperledger Fabric - identity 0 does not satisfy principal: The identity is a member of a different MSP

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to update an existing channel in hyperledger fabric using the node sdk. I am simply trying to increase the batchsize from 10 to 11 (as can be found in the official config update example). My config update looks as follows:

```
{
  "channel_id": "mychannel",
  "read_set": {
    "groups": {
      "Orderer": {}
    }
  },
  "write_set": {
    "groups": {
      "Orderer": {
        "values": {
          "BatchSize": {
            "mod_policy": "Admins",
            "value": {
              "absolute_max_bytes": 102760448,
              "max_message_count": 11,
              "preferred_max_bytes": 524288
            },
            "version": "1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The user enrollment looks as follows:

```
ORG1_TOKEN=$(curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/users \
  -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d 'username=jim&orgName=org1')
```

I run the network on Docker containers and use version 1.0.2 of all images and binaries.

I created an update-channel.js function, very similar to the [create-channel.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/app/create-channel.js) function in the app folder of the balance transfer example. I use the configtxlator to convert the json update into a binary:

```
superagent.post('http://127.0.0.1:7059/protolator/encode/common.ConfigUpdate',
            configFile)
            .buffer()
            .end((error, res) => {
                error ? reject(error) : resolve(res.body);
            });
```

When I sign and push the updated config to the orderer I get the following error message:

```
0xc42011e558 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: The identity is a
   member of a different MSP (expected OrdererMSP, got Org1MSP)
principal evaluation fails 
... 
Rejecting CONFIG_UPDATE because: Error
   authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: Policy for [Values]
   /Channel/Orderer/BatchSize not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit
   threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
```

I can imagine that the problem is related to the fact that I enrolled a user for Org1. Would my solution be to enroll a user on the OrdererOrg (is that even possible)? Or do I need to change my config update json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution. You indeed need the orderer org admin signature. We changed the network-config to also include the admin and mspid information for the orderer and then used the admin to sign the config update:

```
"orderer": {
            "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
            "url": "grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050",
            "server-hostname": "orderer.example.com",
            "tls_cacerts": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt",
            "admin": {
                "key": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore",
                "cert": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/signcerts"
            }
        }
```

The signing object then contains the orderer org admin infos:

```
client.signChannelConfig(channelConfig);
```

This should result in the channel being updated successfully.

This is for **updating any channel config item under the orderer section**. If it is related to the application section, then the signatures of the participating organizations (through their admins) need to be fetched and submitted to the orderer.

Comment: @StephenKennedy, I am facing a similar issue with application section mainly. I have 2 orgs (org1 & org2) setup manually. They are using channel c1. The chaincode invoke works well for org1 but when user of org2 tries to invoke i get access denied. When i debug in the org2 peer logs i find similar error as you mentioned. 

" identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected Org2MSP, got Org1MSP)".  From your solution part I have already updated the config block when adding org2 manually. I am confused any hints would really be helpful